# Symfony2 - Interface within bundle not autoloading

Tags: php, symfony, autoload

I'm having problems loading an interface that I made into my symfony2 project. It is my understanding that Symfony2 is already set up to load the classes in the same namespace as the bundle. However, I am having some problems. My code:

```
//Test/WebBundle/Abstracts/Services/TestInterface.php
<?php

namespace Test\WebBundle\Abstracts\Services;

interface TestInterface{
//...
}

?>

//Test/WebBundle/Implementations/Services/TestService.php
<?php

namespace Test\WebBundle\Implementations\Services;

use Test\WebBundle\Abstracts\Services\TestInterface;

class TestService implements TestInterface{
//...
}

?>
```

And then in my default controller, I have

```
<?php

use Test\WebBundle\Implements\Services\TestService;
//...
$serviceTest = new TestService();
//...
?>
```

Then I get this error:

```
   FatalErrorException: Error: Interface 'Test\WebBundle\Abstracts\Services\TestInterface' not found
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `use` statement has the file extension at the end of the interface name

Change

```
use Test\WebBundle\Abstracts\Services\TestInterface.php
```

to

```
use Test\WebBundle\Abstracts\Services\TestInterface
```

And you should be golden

Comment: Ah, sorry. That was just a typo :x. I fixed it.

Comment: Wait, so that was just a typo in your question - not in your actual codebase?

Comment: D'oh...I figured out what was wrong. Doubled check my spelling for the namespace. Turned out I had Abtracts instead of Abstracts in my code. Thanks for help Peter.